# what does 취할 문형/ 버릴 문형 means ?

Tags: spoken-korean

I got a homework which I need to analyse verb's sentence structure
And there are words 취할 문형, 버릴 문형 in the instruction.
Could you please let me know what is it ? I searched already but cannot find.

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 2):

취할 문형 - The grammatical form to take. (Accepted form)

버릴 문형 - The grammatical form to discard. (Incorrect form)